# why does none retained pointer need to use release?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two questions, but let's start with the more clearly confusing due to simplicity question first.

```
-(void)OnNewFrameData:(NSData *)FrameData 
{
    UIImage * I = [UIImage imageWithData:FrameData];
    [I release];
}
```

If I do not release `I`, I experience a memory leak. Yet, I never retained `I`. Can somone explain this? (`FrameData` is managed by the caller entirely.)

Then I have another question about retained properties. Take the same code above, assign `I` to a retained property `J`, then assign nil to the same retained property, there should not be any leak, but I am leaking memory again. And I can release the retained property as well, but I still get a leak.

```
@property (retain) UIImage * J;

...

-(void)OnNewFrameData:(NSData *)FrameData 
{
    UIImage * I = [UIImage imageWithData:FrameData];
    self.J = I;
    // I can also add here [self.J release]; and it still leaks...
    self.J = nil;
    [I release];
}
```

Insight into these two confusing apparent contradictions from what I have learned from both the documentation and from threads here at stackoverflow would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: How are you determining whether or not your memory is leaking?

Comment: After two or three minutes (not more than that) I get two memory warnings, 1 and 2, and then the program exits by the iOS. The video frames are significant in size, so I figure that they are consuming the memory and not getting released.  I can run the same code for about a half hour and not get any warnings indicating I am not leaking memory. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Use the instruments tool provided with Xcode : http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

Comment: The instruments tool is crashing and doesn't indicate at all why I am getting memory warnings. Or at least its cryptic messages are not giving me much of any clue.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107800/How-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-iPhone-applications

Comment: No place is going to tell you *why* you get memory warnings.  There is only one reason:  too much memory pressure.  Instruments is useful to track your allocations and has a leaks instrument to search for leaks.  If it is crashing, then you have bigger problems than memory warnings.  The basics of memory management are not complicated (if you create it, release it, otherwise leave it alone) and thousands of people have used them without a problem.  So, my guess is the problem is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @user574771 As added below can you check that I is not nil.

Comment: So I decided to go back to the version of code before I tried to ensure memory management and it seems to work fine, so obviously i have some studying to do...    how do I remove this question?

Comment: It seems that `I` is set for autorelease, but that explicitly releasing the object is ensuring it doesn't sit around any longer than it needs to. The frames are coming in about 10fps or more and are about 1MB per frame. It seems to me that if I rely upon autorelease the buffers are not freeing ASAP, but are just pooling up and running me into trouble. Thoughts????

Comment: Is this happening in a thread for which you have not created an autorelease pool

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I tried an experiment with the following code...

```
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImage * Img = [[UIImage imageWithData:FrameData] retain];
    [pool drain];

    int n = [Img retainCount];
```

In the code above, Img's retain count comes back 1. If I remove the auto release pool, it is 2. This is absolutely clear evidence that imageWithData: returns an autoreleased object, and that is exactly what we all expect.

So my only conclusion is that the pool wasn't releasing Img soon enough and they were pooling with each successive image coming over the wire. Eventually I ran out of memory.

If no one has any other ideas on the first part of the original problem I would have to go with this as the answer.

I still have no clue regarding the second issue.

UPDATE:

What had confused me all this time is how do objects on the main thread flagged for auto release get released in a timely manner? I always thought that the auto release was like a garbage collector that operated whenever the memory pool was running out of memory. But looking back at the literature, it is clear that GB is NOT what the auto release pool is about, since it is available in a non GB environment. The auto release pool doesn't release any objects until the pool is destroyed by the drain message.

So what about main thread objects? Why do they not accumulate until the program ends? Because (I speculate here, but it is the most logical explanation) every time the framework calls into one of our class objects (UPDATE: I am talking about the framework calling our code whenever it dispatches an event), it first sets up a new auto release pool. Thus all objects in any method call to one of our class objects made by the framework is surrounded by a fresh pool and all objects flagged for auto release are released when the framework receives control back from our code.

If anyone has any information to shed more light onto this I would very much like to hear from you.

Comment: No. No no no no no. Don't touch `-retainCount`. Pretend that method doesn't exist. I don't care what you're doing, just don't.

Comment: I am acutely aware of the problems with accessing retainCount. I accessed here only to test the behavior of [pool drain] on what we all assume is an autorelease object reference from imageWithData.

Comment: It is interesting how someone voted down my answer, but could not explain what I was seeing with any better explanation...

Comment: Your speculation is wrong. The main thread only gets 1 autorelease pool by default, which is created by the `NSRunLoop`. Every time it dispatches an event it creates a new pool. And there is absolutely no GC-like behavior here. Autoreleased objects get destroyed precisely when their surrounding autorelease pool is released.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? Okay, I didn't say "dispatches an event", but I did say "every time the framework calls into one of our class objects". I suspect your description is more accurate in wording only..

Comment: You've deleted your speculation now, but from what I recall you seemed to imply that arbitrary framework methods would establish autorelease pools, and you also said something about an assumption of GC-like behavior.

Answer (score -1):

`[UIImage imageWithData]` is a convenience method that does something like the below.

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithData:(NSData*)data{
   UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
   [img autorelease];

   return img;
}
```

so as you can see there is a alloc setting the retain count at one. hope this clarifies. Leave a comment if I can clarify further. I have just been prompted that the image will be placed in an autorelease pool, and there for should be retained upon creation if you want to persist it after pool drain.

the correct way would then be to use.

```
 [[UIImage imageWithdata:data]retain];
```

In doing this it will have a retain count of 2 which will reduce by one upon pool drain. Therefor you should still only need a single release.

p.s you may also want to run the analyser. It will point out any memory problems. (CMD + shift + b)

Another thought. Can you check that i is not nil. The docs say that if it is unsuccessful in the creation of the UIImage it will return nil, which may be a problem.

Comment: I dont think this is correct, since `imageWithData:` isn't an `alloc`, `new`, or `copy` etc named method it should return an autoreleased object